# Viewport 3D WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, viewport3d

Can you please show how to set and save the background color of the viewport3D. Whenever I save no background is visible only model, I tried the grid but that gets everything in the grid? Any help will do?

Answer (score 2):

Viewport3D doesn't have a Background property so you need something behind it.

your approach using a Grid is right, you might want to use a Border to enforce the
use of a single child.

```
 <Border Background="Green">
  <Viewport3D Width="640.0" Height="480.0" >
    <ModelVisual3D/>
  </Viewport3D>
</Border>
```

I assume you are using XamlWriter, XamlReader . Just save the border instead of the Viewport3D and everything inside the border will be saved as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have provided some code for this, please verify it.

```
<Viewport3D>
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera Position="2,0,10" LookDirection="0.2,0.4,-1" FieldOfView="65" UpDirection="0,1,0">
                </PerspectiveCamera>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <Model3DGroup>
                        <AmbientLight Color="#fff"/>
                        <GeometryModel3D>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <MeshGeometry3D Positions="0,0,0 0,10,0 10,0,0 10,10,0"
                                                Normals="0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1 0,0,1"
                                                TriangleIndices="0,2,1,1,2,3"/>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Red"/>
                            </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        </GeometryModel3D>
                    </Model3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
```